# How to Execute script in multiple databases at once

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Sql Server

I have sample script

```
Declare @V table (name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @V(name)
 select name  from sys.databases where database_id > 6

select NAME from @V
```

If I execute this Script I get the user databases list

In my instance I have below Databases :

```
DatabaseName
mohan
Ravi
```

How can I dynamically append the Database names to below script and execute the script in below Databases

```
Declare @V table (ID INT,name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @V(Id,name)
 select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY NAME),name  from sys.databases where database_id > 6

 DECLARE @LoopCounter INT , @MaxId INT, 
        @Name NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT @LoopCounter = min(id) , @MaxId = max(Id) 
FROM @V

WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL
      AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxId)
BEGIN
   SELECT @Name = Name
   FROM @V WHERE Id = @LoopCounter

   PRINT @Name  
   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1        
END


DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50) =   @Name
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
+'CREATE TABLE T(ID INT)';

--PRINT(@SQL);


EXECUTE(@SQL);
```

So in all user databases Table will be created . I have tried with sp_msforeachdb

script :

```
DECLARE @Sql AS VARCHAR(4000)
SET @Sql = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''tempdb'',''model'',''msdb'',''ReportServer'',''ReportServerTempDB'') 
                        EXECUTE ('' USE [?] CREATE TABLE T (ID INT)'')'
                        EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = @Sql
```

But I'm looking for looping  script .How to append those names to the Script

Comment: And now you're trying to run the same script but with MySQL instead of MS SQL Server?

Comment: No it's purely MS SQL I have tagged MYSQL it will reach more SO's so that they can suggest me @jarlh please find my updated script

Comment: You must be kidding, 4543 points and doing newbie tagging.

Comment: @Jarlh is right.  Please don't add extra tags.  MySQL and SQL Server solutions are often incompatible.

Comment: haha @jarlh In tags it's suggesting us to do . ok I will remove that tag then

Comment: Yeah, that tag suggestion is plain stupid.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop here.  You can generate the entire statement in one pass.  This query populates a var that contains multiple USE and CREATE TABLE statements:

```
DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- Build dynamic SQL statement here.
-- 1 Row returned per target database .
SELECT
    @Qry +=  
        '
            USE' + QUOTENAME(Name) + ';

            CREATE TABLE T
                (
                    ID INT 
                )
            ;
        ' 
FROM    
    sys.Databases
WHERE
    database_id > 6
;


-- Remove comments from last line when happy with query.
PRINT @Qry
--EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @Qry
```

Returns

```
USE [X];

CREATE TABLE T
    (
        ID INT
    )
;

USE [Y];

CREATE TABLE T
    (
        ID INT
    )
;
...
```

Comment: it is not working . can you please look at the updated script

Comment: You are you using `PRINT @Qry` or `EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @Qry` as the last line?  Can you test @Qry in SSMS?  Does it parse?